# An error occurred while running C:\Users\path marketplace1\marketplace1\truffle-config.js! Did you forget to `npm install` your project?

Tags: truffle, ganache

I am getting this error when I try to add the truffle-config file to my project in ganache. What to do?[image: ganache error]

Comment: did you forget to 'npm install' ? please also add which version of ganache are you using and your global truffle version.